# Как отправить запрос с TLS 1.2 c windows embeded POSReady 2009?

Tags: c#, .net, tls

Есть ком-объект который отправляет запросы на сервер (.net Framework 2.0).
Сервер принимает только TLS 1.2.
Сначала получал ошибку:

```
 System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```

Добавил строку:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)48 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Стал получать ошибку:

```
The requested security protocol is not supported.   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.set_SecurityProtocol(SecurityProtocolType value)
```

Можно что нибудь придумать, без обновления .net версии?
P.S. Вторую ошибку получаю только с embeded POSReady 2009. Отправляю с windows 10, всё хорошо.

Comment: Скорее всего придется использовать third-party имплементацию TLS, например BouncyCastle

Comment: Here you can read this to get it working: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows